# Vue2.js and Firebase looping with v-for and :key can't get value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vuejs2, v-for

Looping through a Firebase project using v-for and having a devil of a time trying to get one value (imgurl) for each item. Here are a couple rows form the firebase object:

[firebase data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo6ib.png)

Here is my script code in App.vue.

```
<script>
import Firebase from "firebase";
let config = {
   …all correct blah blah…
};
let app = Firebase.initializeApp(config);
let db = app.database();
let itemsRef = db.ref("tblItems");
export default {
  name: "app",
  firebase: {
    items: itemsRef
  },
  data() {
    return {
      styleObject: {
        backgroundImage: "" //RIGHT IN HERE I NEED item.imgname BUT CAN'T FIGURE OUT SYNTAX.
           }      
    };
  }
};
```

Here is where I loop through using v-for and key and I call StyleObject.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
      <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" v-bind:style="styleObject"> 
         <h1>{{ item.title }}</h1>
         <h2>{{ item.author }}</h2> 
    </div> 
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Everything works fine, except I can't figure you how to get **item.imgname** where the RIGHT IN HERE comment is so I can use it for a background image in a style= attribute (each div has its own background image). Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the easiest way to do that is to make de div into a new component and to pass the image name as a prop into it. Your component will then look like this:

```
Vue.component('exampleDiv', {
  props: ['imgname','title','author'],
  template: '<div :style="styleObject"> 
     <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
     <h2>{{ author }}</h2> 
     </div> ',
    data() {
        return {
            styleObject: {
                backgroundImage: this.imgname
            }
         }
})
```

You can then call the component in your code like this:

```
<template>
      <div id="app">
          <exampleDiv v-for="item in items" 
               :key="item.id" :title="item.title" 
               :author="item.author" :imgname = "item.imgname"> 
        </exampleDiv> 
        <router-view/>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've read all those but still not figured out the magic syntax for what I'm trying to do. I've tried everything that seemed remotely reasonable to me so far. But there's obviously something I don't understand yet.

Comment: Tried to put in some code. Don't have time to test this extensively right now. Please let me know if it works out for you.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't update with each pass through the loop. It gets me the whole array. I need the **item.imgname** that's unique with each pass through the loop, like **{{item.imgname}}** in a template, but in a format where I can use it as an image name in a **style=background-image(...)** for each div. See my updated code in previous answer. I keep checking the docs, but I can't seem to get this one thing.

Comment: I understand better what you want to do now. Please see my updated answer.